# Force absolute redirection to another domain in asp.net core without http prefix?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have asp.net core web app with the following redirect statment:

```
return  Redirect(result);
```

the "result" variable is user supplied and thus can be example.com or http://www.example.com. if result is http://www.example.com redirection work as intended. but if result is "example.com" the redirection goes to a relative path (e.g. mysite.com/redirectto/example.com ).

i wand to always force absolute redirect no matter what the value of the "result" variable.

Comment: You can always check for whether the result starts with http:// and if not prefix it and redirect right?

Comment: i did that ,it works thanks